# Service Fabric upgrades keep active connections alive

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to upgrade an application deployed to service fabric.
How can I only upgrade nodes that have no active connections and wait for the busy nodes to finish before upgrading them?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, you don't really have to worry about the upgrades on a node level as the SF runtime handles it internally if configured in Monitored mode. This is what we've been using with a high level of success and never really had to do much. This also fit our requirement that all upgrade domains (nodes) have to match our health state policies before considered healthy.

If you want to have more advanced control over your upgrades like using request draining etc, have a look at the info [as mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-advanced). But to be honest, we've been quite happy with just using monitored mode and investigating why stuff fails if it does. We had some apps that had a long background task running as a stateful actor that sometimes failed upgrade and most always it was due to an issue that was caused in the background task itself instead of anything to do with Service Fabric.

Service Fabric knew when no active connections and background tasks were running to then upgrade nodes and we could actually see the nodes that were temporarily 'stuck' due to waiting for an active background task to finish.